# Protected variables in C++

Tags: c++, class, sdl-2

So, working with some classes and inheritance, I created an Entity class which inherits from an ImageShape class which inherits from an abstract Shape class.
I also have a Wall class inheriting from a RectShape class, which inherits from the same abstact Shape class.

I need to work around collisions, so I called Wall to be Entity's friend class and went on to create a function using Entity's protected x, y, newx, newy fields and Wall's protected x, y, width, height fields.

when compiling, the compiler tells me Entity's variables are protected, but from my understanding I should be able to use them if Wall is friend of Entity;

Here are my classes:
1. Entity class

```
class Shape
{

public:
    virtual void show(point offset = point(), bool doStroke = false) = 0;
    virtual void setColor(SDL_Color col) {color = col;}
    virtual void setStrokeColor(SDL_Color col) {strokeColor = col;}

protected:
    SDL_Renderer *gRenderer;
    SDL_Color color;
    SDL_Color strokeColor;
};
```

```
class ImageShape : public Shape
{
public:
    ImageShape();
    ImageShape(SDL_Renderer *&iRenderer, int iX, int iY);

    bool loadFromFile(std::string path);
    void show(point offset = point(), bool doStroke = false);
    void free();


protected:
    double x, y;
    int width, height;
    SDL_Texture* mTexture;

    double angle;
    SDL_RendererFlip flip;
};
```

```
class Entity : public ImageShape
{
    friend class Wall;
public:
    Entity();
    Entity(SDL_Renderer *&gRenderer, int iX, int iY, double iSpeed, double iMaxSpeed, double iJumpPower);
    point getCenterCoords();
    void collisionWall(Wall wall);
    void spin();

protected:
    int newx, newy;
    double dx, newdx, dy, newdy;
    double speed, maxSpeed;
    int jumpPower;
    bool currentlyJumping;

};
```

2.Wall class

```
class RectShape : public Shape
{

public:
    RectShape();
    RectShape(SDL_Renderer *iRenderer, int iX, int iY, int iWidth, int iHeight, SDL_Color iColor, SDL_Color iStrokeColor = {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00});
    void show(point offset = point(), bool doStroke = false);

protected:
    double x, y;
    int width, height;
};
```

```
class Wall : public RectShape
{

public:
    Wall();
    Wall(SDL_Renderer *iRenderer, int iX, int iY, int iWidth, int iHeight, SDL_Color iColor, SDL_Color iStrokeColor = {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00});
    void setState(bool state) {Enabled = state;}
    bool getState() {return Enabled;}

private:
    bool Enabled;
};
```

3.This is the collision function

```
void Entity::collisionWall(Wall wall)
{
    //Collision right
    if(   x >= wall.x + wall.width &&
       newx <= wall.x + wall.width &&
       newy + height >= wall.y     &&
       newy <= wall.y + wall.height  )
    {
         if(newdx > -6)
           newdx = 0;
         newdx = -newdx;
         newx = wall.x + wall.width;
    }

    //Collision left
    if(    x + width <= wall.x     &&
        newx + width >= wall.x     &&
        newy + height >= wall.y    &&
        newy <= wall.y + wall.height )
    {
          if(newdx < 6)
           newdx = 0;
         newdx = -newdx;
         newx = wall.x - width;
    }

    //Collision top
    if(   y + height <= wall.y   &&
         newy + height >= wall.y   &&
         newx + width >= wall.x    &&
         newx <= wall.x + wall.width )
    {
          newdy = 0;
          newy = wall.y - height;
          if(currentlyJumping)
            currentlyJumping = false;
    }

   //Collision bot
    if(    y >= wall.y + wall.height &&
        newy <= wall.y + wall.height &&
        newx + width >= wall.x       &&
        newx <= wall.x + wall.width    )
          {
           newdy = -newdy / 4;
           newy = wall.y + wall.height;
          }
}
```

also, here are part of the errors I get:

```
||=== Build: Debug in The jump, again (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
 again\shape.h||In member function 'void Entity::collisionWall(Wall)':|
 again\shape.h|31|error: 'double RectShape::x' is protected|
 again\Entity.cpp|51|error: within this context|
 again\shape.h|32|error: 'int RectShape::width' is protected|
 again\Entity.cpp|51|error: within this context|
 again\shape.h|31|error: 'double RectShape::x' is protected|
 again\Entity.cpp|52|error: within this context|
 again\shape.h|32|error: 'int RectShape::width' is protected|
 again\Entity.cpp|52|error: within this context|
 again\shape.h|31|error: 'double RectShape::y' is protected|
 again\Entity.cpp|53|error: within this context|
 again\shape.h|31|error: 'double RectShape::y' is protected|
 again\Entity.cpp|54|error: within this context|
 again\shape.h|32|error: 'int RectShape::height' is protected|
 again\Entity.cpp|54|error: within this context|
 again\shape.h|31|error: 'double RectShape::x' is protected|
 again\Entity.cpp|59|error: within this context|
 again\shape.h|32|error: 'int RectShape::width' is protected|
 again\Entity.cpp|59|error: within this context|
 again\shape.h|31|error: 'double RectShape::x' is protected|
 again\Entity.cpp|63|error: within this context|
 again\shape.h|31|error: 'double RectShape::x' is protected|
 again\Entity.cpp|64|error: within this context|
 again\shape.h|31|error: 'double RectShape::y' is protected|
 again\Entity.cpp|65|error: within this context|
 again\shape.h|31|error: 'double RectShape::y' is protected|
 again\Entity.cpp|66|error: within this context|
 again\shape.h|32|error: 'int RectShape::height' is protected|
 again\Entity.cpp|66|error: within this context|
 again\shape.h|31|error: 'double RectShape::x' is protected|
 again\Entity.cpp|71|error: within this context|
 again\shape.h|31|error: 'double RectShape::y' is protected|
 again\Entity.cpp|75|error: within this context|
 again\shape.h|31|error: 'double RectShape::y' is protected|
 again\Entity.cpp|76|error: within this context|
 again\shape.h|31|error: 'double RectShape::x' is protected|
 again\Entity.cpp|77|error: within this context|
 again\shape.h|31|error: 'double RectShape::x' is protected|
 again\Entity.cpp|78|error: within this context|
 again\shape.h|32|error: 'int RectShape::width' is protected|
 again\Entity.cpp|78|error: within this context|
 again\shape.h|31|error: 'double RectShape::y' is protected|
 again\Entity.cpp|81|error: within this context|
 again\shape.h|31|error: 'double RectShape::y' is protected|
 again\Entity.cpp|87|error: within this context|
 again\shape.h|32|error: 'int RectShape::height' is protected|
 again\Entity.cpp|87|error: within this context|
 again\shape.h|31|error: 'double RectShape::y' is protected|
 again\Entity.cpp|88|error: within this context|
 again\shape.h|32|error: 'int RectShape::height' is protected|
 again\Entity.cpp|88|error: within this context|
||More errors follow but not being shown.|
||Edit the max errors limit in compiler options...|
||=== Build failed: 50 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 2 second(s)) ===|
```

Comment: That does not answer your question, but it should be something to think about. You use `protected` or `private` so that you make parts of the implementation not accessible from outside so that it is easier to maintain (e.g. allows you to control what values they have or enabling an easier refactoring). Using `friend` weakens that benefit. So whenever you use `friend` you should think about if this is really what you want to do. In many cases, you want to use a `public` member function instead that exposes controlled access to the private members.

Comment: you mean, getters for wall's x, y, width and height?

Comment: For example. How you define those getters depends on you. The getters could be for `x`, `y`, `width` and `height` individually they could be  `vec2 position()` and `vec2 size()`,  or all of them. They do not necessarily need to relate to the internal structure in any way. But they allow you to change the internal structure at any time.

Comment: I don't want to say `friend` is bad in general, but you should always think about if it is the right approach. E.g. it only limits set additional class should be able to read or set the internal data, then `friend` might be perfectly fine and necessary. But for position and size of shape it is likely that you will need to access it at many other places.

Comment: You could have made this question less likely to be skipped over if you had trimmed down your code. For example, you could reduce `collisionWall` to no more than the first `if` statement (with a comment to indicate that more code appears in the real version). Then remove all members (functions and data, of all classes) that are not needed to reproduce the compiler error. Also simplify your inheritance chains -- skip `ImageShape`, and possibly `Shape` as well.

Answer (score 1):

Argh, I got it.
Friending Wall meant that Wall could access Entity's protected variables.
I needed to friend Entity in Wall instead!